# Fragments compose ViewPager layout, delay on creation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an app with ViewPager that contains 4 Classes extends Fragment. i've follow tutorials on internet, but now i have occurred in a strange problem.
This is constructor of fragment adapter:

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;
TableFragment table_fragment;
MixFragment mix_fragment;
HumFragment hum_fragment;
TempFragment temp_fragment;

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    Log.i("AAAAAA", "FragmentAdapter constructor");
    table_fragment = new TableFragment();
    mix_fragment = new MixFragment();
    hum_fragment = new HumFragment();
    temp_fragment = new TempFragment();
}
```

and this is one of the fragment compose ViewPager (the others look similar):

```
public class TableFragment extends Fragment {
MainActivity main;
ListView list_view;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);
    list_view = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
```

Now, i've noticed that, after in my mainactivity i create a new FragmentAdapter object, the onCreateView() method of fragment isn't call immediatly, and my app crash (because each fragment have some methods that modify the fragment content). 
How can i do for avoid this? i need that Fragments are created immediatly, so i can perform action on its

Comment: you cannot force the creation immediately - just delay your task that works on them a little bit an then it should be fine. If find this the easiest way.

Comment: i was thinking to put inside main activity an idle (for example by using Thread.sleep() ) inside onCreate(), but i don't know how many seconds wait for it (and if from one execution to other the required time it's more?). Maybe there's a way to block main activity onCreate and wait a sort of message from Fragments where after they perform onCreateView?

Comment: No, I would not block main activity, the system may kill your app if you wait too long - but it sounds strange, I would suspect the problem somewhere else now after your comment

Comment: Main activity just initialize the ViewPager elements and start a Service. I don't want stop statically, maybe i could use a circle progress bar for idle, so the app appear not inactive.